# How to update the kernel in eOS 0.4 Loki to solve hardware-related issues?

Tags: release-loki, updates, kernel

I recently bought an Asus Zenbook UX305UA and installed my favorite operating system version 0.4. Most things work out of the box. However, I ran into a few issues which are hardware-related, but seem to be resolved in newer versions of the kernel, these are:

- [USB devices are not recognized in battery mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310641/usb-devices-not-recognized-when-laptop-runs-on-battery)
- Brightness control keys (Fn + F5/F6) don't work
- Airplane mode key (Fn + F2) doesn't work

I have found how-tos on updating the kernel, but I have also read that one shouldn't do it if he has no clue about it (i.e. my situation). Others wrote about kernel fixes being backported, so how can I check for these backports and are they fetched automatically or where can I get them?

I would relly love to stick with elementary, but I think I couldn't live with these issues, especially the USB device thing. So can someone tell me whether I can expect an automatic kernel update / backport or provide some advice on how to savely update the kernel myself? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Kernel updates are included through updates to the Ubuntu base. Loki is based on Ubuntu 16.04, which will get updates every 6 months for the next 5 years. (See the [Ubuntu releases page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for more details).

The last release was in July, so I'd expect the next one to arrive in January 2017.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know! Thank you! So, are those updates automatically comming through to elementary? Because with the new AppCenter it's hard to tell what it let's through and what not. Is there a way to check whether I received those updates (e.g. the one from July)?